# How to receive faint AM light

Tags: wireless, light, amplitude-modulation

I am going to be amplitude modulating a high power LED light from a peak on a mountain. I want to recieve this faint light as far as physically possible before the light fades out too much to recieve.

What is a practical way with high gain to recieve this light to be amplified for a speaker?

EDIT:
I would like the beam to travel about 2 miles or 4Km from nearby bergen peak visible from my house. Here is a Google Earth image:

AS a 15yr old experimenter, my budget is mainly limited to 75 dollars due to all my other projects I am working on. 
[image]

Comment: How far is as far as physically possible? Using light for this purpose will not be easy.

Comment: There are some satellites in orbit that digitally communicate via IR. IR is selected because it penetrates the atmosphere better than visible light. Columnized, filtered are a necessity for long range. You may need a telescope at one or both ends. If AM fails you try digital PWM.

Comment: @Optionparty: If one uses IR, how would one go about focusing lens-based telescopes?  If my understanding of physics is correct, the required lens placement for infinity at IR wavelengths would likely differ from that for visible wavelengths, though the amount of difference would vary depending upon the lens coatings used.

Comment: It will differ from visible but it is one way of achieving some columnizing, another would be a mirror. As I understand it, light only travel about 1,000 its beam diameter before it starts diverging, even if only slightly (Gaussian waist). So you will want to select a beam for your intended range.

Comment: Many LED's can double as detectors, with spectrally selective filters for their own output frequency.
http://web.archive.org/web/20101127155013/http://sas.org/tcs/weeklyIssues_2009/2009-02-06/feature1/index.html
 There is a simple circuit in this article 
http://web.archive.org/web/20101224114905/http://www.sas.org/tcs/weeklyIssues/2004-06-25/backscatter/index.html

Comment: "Popular Electronics" has published several articles. Here is a link to one that says it will work over several miles. http://www.rfcafe.com/references/popular-electronics/laser-beam-communicator-may-1970-popular-electronics.htm

Comment: The greatest distance (119 miles) I have found on the web. Lots of links. http://www.modulatedlight.org/

Comment: SKYLER - ALMOST 6 YEARS LATER. dID YOU GET ANYWHERE WITH THIS PROJEC? iF SO, WHAT DID YOU ENED UP USING AS tx & rx - rUSSELL

Comment: I wish I could say I did, but got busy with other things. I ended up getting a avalanche photo diode, and constructed a circuit to amplify this signal, however, I never was able to get the amplification to work right with the electronics knowledge I had.

Answer (score 2):

A telescope (large as possible) followed by a photomultiplier. That will give you all the gain you can handle: you will be able to pick up single photons.

Now you have a different problem: ambient light. You want to *not* recieve this. This is what signal/noise ratio of the channel means in your context. Amplitude modulation will very much limit what you can do to improve this. Note that a continuous light seen at a distance will waver slightly in heat haze.

If you're trying to do this in the daytime, your range will be greatly limited. At night with a large LED lantern or multiple-watt CREE light and a small astronomical telescope you could probably get decent results with digital audio over several kilometers. You could also improve results with a laser as a transmitter, even a 5mw pointer, although you then have to align both ends rather than just one while avoiding looking down the telescope with the naked eye.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I edited my question with more specific details

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper term (to be able to search for designs and papers about this) is "free space optical" communication. Many people have already given links, but here is a design for an open-hardware point-to-point FSO link:

[Ronja Project](http://ronja.twibright.com/)

It's probably more complex than you need if you just want to transmit analog voice, but the analog front-end design might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide more details (e.g. wavelength, ambient light levels, distance, budget, etc).

In general, I would consider using avalanche photo diodes for detection. They are relatively low noise and provide good gain.  You also need a pretty narrowband optical filter to filter out ambient noise. 
Powering APDs is not too easy since you have to provide a relatively large voltage (100-200V). Also, you may need to do some temperature compensation since APDs are very temperature sensitive devices.